# How can I load a font in Eclipse w/o installing it in your native OS?

Tags: java, eclipse, fonts

I'd like to use this font for coding in Eclipse but I don't have any admin rights. I can't install any font in WINDOWS/font folder. Any workaround?

thanks in advance!

http://damieng.com/blog/2007/11/14/droid-font-family-courtesy-of-google-ascender

Answer (score 2):

Try [`Font.createFont(int, java.io.InputStream)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#createFont%28int,%20java.io.InputStream%29) method. It loads font from a file. You can then derive it to get needed size.